# Serial number from Samsung Device running Android

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 (7")

On the back of this device is a serial number of the format

RF3C6000MNA

When I go into settings on my device, and choose About Device->Status->Serial Number, this number also appears.

I can't, however, find a way of extracting this number programmatically.

I've seen loads of articles about extracting the serial number, but this returns a completely different number. (using android.os.Build.SERIAL)

I've already extracted the IMEI, and MAC address, so I don't need code for this.

Comment: have you tried [how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) it?

Comment: Yes, but none of those solutions return the same serial number that's printed on the back of the device, and displayed in the 'Status' screen in settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read serial number on a Samsung device (from within app / on the device)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732147/how-to-read-serial-number-on-a-samsung-device-from-within-app-on-the-device)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
public static String getManufacturerSerialNumber() {
  String serial = null; 
  try {
      Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
      Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);
      serial = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber", "unknown");
  } catch (Exception ignored) {}
  return serial;
}
```

**Edit:** it's been a while since this answer, here's a couple of updated points:

- The OP asked about **Galaxy Tab 2** and for that indeed the answer was `ril.serialnumber` (even for the non-3G model - see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jgold6/f46b1c049a1ee94fdb52)). According to Himanshu's answer **Galaxy Tab 3** uses `sys.serialnumber` (also backed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27274950/1027527)). `sys.serialnumber` makes better sense for tablets as `ril.*` stands for *Radio Interface Layer*, something most tablets are not equipped with (`ril.serialnumber`, respectively, makes better sense for phones).
- There is no standard API for getting the device serial number (ie the serial number on the packaging - **not to be confused** with `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` or the various other "unique" identifiers scattered throughout the API). This means it is up to the manufacturer to decide where to store the device serial (if at all). On the **S3 Mini** it's `ril.serialnumber`, on **NexusOne** it's `ro.serialno` ([gist](https://gist.github.com/tetsu-koba/992373)), on **Galaxy Tab 2** it's `ril.serialnumber`, on **Galaxy Tab 3/4** it's `sys.serialnumber`, on **Lenovo Tab** it's [none of the above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773975/how-to-get-real-serial-number-of-lenovo-tab-in-android). These settings appear to be the usual suspects, when looking for the device serial, but shouldn't be taken for granted, and as such, shouldn't be relied on for tracking unique app installations.

Comment: Fantastic, even Samsung didn't know how to get this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Will this code give the serial number for all manufacturers or only for Samsung galaxy?

Comment: ril.serialnumber works on Galaxy Camera 1 (EK GC100 models), probably Galaxy Camera 2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getprop` command on the adb shell and check yourself that which of the files contains the correct serial number. Many times the serial number is located in different files and a code has to be device specific.

For samung Tab 3 you can use the following code:

```
try {

        Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");

        Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);

        serialnum = (String) (get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber", "unknown"));

    } catch (Exception ignored) {

        serialnum = "unknown";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the Build class for our product.  See if this matches: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL