# Android: How to get the Serial Number as shown in About Device, Status with Java

Tags: java, android

On my Android Tablet I go to Settings -> About Device -> Status
In this screen I find a serial number with a length of 11 characters.
I would like to read this serial number with Java.
Anyone an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
String x = Build.SERIAL
```

For more details [check this out.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)
This is the device serial number.

For MDN or MEID of the device depending on which radio the phone uses (GSM or CDMA), try

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

and include the permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Build.SERIAL gives a number of 16 characters.
This is not the one in Settings -> About Device -> Status which has 11 characters

Answer (score 2):

Very old question, but perhaps the solution from dev [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18071939) still helps:

```
public static String getManufacturerSerialNumber() {
String serial = null; 
try {
  Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
  Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);
  serial = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber", "unknown");
} catch (Exception ignored) {}
return serial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
String serial = Build.SERIAL;
tv.setText(serial);
```

Comment: Can't test this because I'm making a app using Phonegap, so my output is in html/javascript.
The Build.SERIAL is the serial number you see when running "adb devices"