# How to get real serial number of lenovo tab in android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the serial number of my Lenovo Idea Tab running Android. I tried all the options available in Google search, which are:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);  
String serial = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber" );
String serial_no = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno");
String serial_no1 = (String) get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber");
```

`ro.serialno` is giving a value as `8TYDE67HYLUOZPOZ`, but the serial number shown in "Status -> About Tablet" is `HGC2TKH4`, and the printed serial number in the back side of the tab is also `HGC2TKH4`.

`ril.serialnumber` and `sys.serialnumber` are empty.

In some other tabs also, the `ril.serialnumber` is empty, but it is supposed to have the serial number, I hope.

Please, how can I find the real serial number of my device on Android?

Answer (score 6):

I recently had to also get the SN for a lenovo tablet.
You can use the following methods

```
public static String getIMEI(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return telephonyManager != null ? (telephonyManager.getDeviceId() != null ? telephonyManager.getDeviceId() : "N/A") : "N/A";
}

public static String getSN() {
    String deviceSN = "N/A";
    try {
        Class<?> propClass = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        Method getProp = propClass.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);
        deviceSN = (String) getProp.invoke(propClass, "gsm.sn1", "N/A");
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return deviceSN;
}

public static String getPN() {
    String devicePN = "N/A";
    try {
        Class<?> propClass = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        Method getProp = propClass.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);
        devicePN = (String) getProp.invoke(propClass, "ro.lenovosn2", "N/A");
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return devicePN;
}
```

Lenovo has custom property names, you can use the following adb command to see all available props:

```
adb shell getprop
```

Comment: To get the serial # on the back use 'ro.lenovosn2'.  That is not the product number.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to get the serial number from the Lenovo tab 7 Essential (2017 model running Android 7.0).  I was also using it to get Samsung serial numbers (Galaxy Camera 1/2 running Android 4 and a Tab A running 6, then updated to 7.1.1).

```
private static String UNKNOWN = "unknown";
static String GetDeviceSerialNumber() {
    String serial;
    if (Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase().contains("lenovo")) {
        serial = GetLenovoManufacturerSerialNumber();
    } else {
        serial = GetSamsungManufacturerSerialNumber();
    }
    if (serial == null || serial.equals(UNKNOWN)) {
        serial = Build.SERIAL; // this is NOT usually the serial displayed on the device, but it returns something
    }
    return serial;
}
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161282/serial-number-from-samsung-device-running-android
private static String GetSamsungManufacturerSerialNumber() {
    String serial = GetSystemPropertyString("ril.serialnumber"); // older Samsung devices - works on Galaxy Camera 1
    if (serial == null || serial.equals(UNKNOWN)) {
        serial = GetSystemPropertyString("sys.serialnumber"); // newer Samsung devices
    }
    return serial;
}
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773975/how-to-get-real-serial-number-of-lenovo-tab-in-android
private static String GetLenovoManufacturerSerialNumber() {
    return GetSystemPropertyString("ro.lenovosn2");
}
private static String GetSystemPropertyString(String prop) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);
        return (String)get.invoke(c, prop, UNKNOWN);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hopefully that's helpful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

HI you can get everything about your device hardware by using the following code.

```
Build.BRAND  //Brand Name

Build.DEVICE   //Device Name

Build.MODEL   //Model No

Build.SERIAL  //Serial No
```

import this namespace :: `import android.os.Build;`

Let me know if my answer is right or not.

Comment: Thanks for the support. But in my SDK version Build.Serial is not available. But everything else is there like Brand, Model, Device, ID etc. How do we resolve this?

Comment: Build.Serial was added in API 9. SO it will be available based on your API Version. It will be available above API 9