# How to get a device's serial no with Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

Does anybody know how to get the serial number of a device?

I know I can do this in a NativeScript-5 application (TypeScript):

```
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";    
import * as platformModule from "tns-core-modules/platform";

export function onNavigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;

    console.log("Manufacturer:" + platformModule.device.manufacturer);
    console.log("Model:" + platformModule.device.model);
    console.log("UUID:" + platformModule.device.uuid);
}
```

But I couldnt find any property for the device's serial number. 
Anybody an idea? It's alright if your solution only covers Android (since my project is targeting Android tablets only).

Thanks!

**Update:**

Manoj pointed me to some Java code that probably solves my problem. However, I wasn't able to marshal the following code to TypeScript.

```
      public static String getManufacturerSerialNumber() { 
          String serial = null; 
          try {
               Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
               Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);
               serial = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber", "unknown");
          } catch (Exception ignored) {}
          return serial;
      }
```

Maybe anybody could help me? That would be awesome!

Comment: Are you referring to the IMEI number?

Comment: Nope, not the IMEI. I mean the real serial number of the device.

Comment: In my tablet's settings I find "model number" and "serial number". It's the serial number that I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS never allows any confidential information to be accessed by apps, that applies to serial number too. With Android, you may read the serial number with

```
android.os.Build.SERIAL
```

I had it tested with [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=ViNo6g)

**Edit 1:**

Manufactures like Samsung seems to have a different serial number which is not same as [android.os.Build.SERIAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build#SERIAL). [Here is another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161282/serial-number-from-samsung-device-running-android) that seems very relevant for Samsung, the sample code is written in Java.

**Edit 2:**

Here is how you may get serial number on Samsung devices

```
        let serialNumber = ''; 
        try {
            const cl = application.android.context.getClassLoader();
            const SystemProperties = cl.loadClass('android.os.SystemProperties');

            const paramTypes = (<any>Array).create(java.lang.Class, 2);
            paramTypes[0] = java.lang.String.class;
            paramTypes[1] = java.lang.String.class;
            const getMethod = SystemProperties.getMethod('get', paramTypes);

            const params = (<any>Array).create(java.lang.Object, 2);
            params[0] = new java.lang.String('ril.serialnumber');
            params[1] = new java.lang.String('unknown');

            serialNumber = getMethod.invoke(SystemProperties, params);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=ViNo6g&v=3)

Comment: Hello Manoj, amazing how many IDs a device has. On my Samsung Galaxy Tablet your code returns "330050c2712865fb" which is actually the ID that NativeScript's CLI displays when I do "tns run". Except, this still is not the serial number I am looking for. On my tablet, when I go into "Settings > About tablet" I can see a "Serial number: R52K90L6TZH". This is also the number which is printed on the box and a sticker on the device. It's also the number that Samsung Knox uses for MDM. Weird, so many numbers ...

Comment: Samsung / MI brands do customise the Android for their device. As per the official android documentation, this is the API we should use and it works on my Moto G5+ which is a true (untouched) Android from Google. I will still take a look if I find anything on Samsung.

Comment: Thank you so much, Manoj. I also keep on researching ... if you find a solution for Samsung that's good enough for my purposes.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to other SO thread that has multiple solutions for Samsnug, except it's written in Java. I hope you may able to marshall that into JS / TS.

Comment: Not sure. Will have a look at this on the weekend ;) Thanks for now, Manoj.

Comment: Let me know in case if you find it hard. I will have to find my old Samsung Tablet if I have to test this.

Comment: Damn. Wasn't able to solve this one. Tried to access "android.os.SystemProperties" by following https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/accessing-packages#access-android-classes, but ended up ... nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can check properties 'ro.serialno', 'ril.serialnumber', 'gsm.sn1', 'sys.serialnumber'

[Android: How to programmatically access the device serial number shown in the AVD manager (API Version 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029294/android-how-to-programmatically-access-the-device-serial-number-shown-in-the-av)

In my case Samsung TAB S2 has 2 serials. Property 'ro.serialno' more accurate then 'ril.serialnumber'. So i check it first.

```
getSerial() {
  if (isAndroid) {
    let serialNumber = null;
    try {
      const cl = application.android.context.getClassLoader();
      const SystemProperties = cl.loadClass('android.os.SystemProperties');

      const paramTypes = (<any>Array).create(java.lang.Class, 2);
      paramTypes[0] = java.lang.String.class;
      paramTypes[1] = java.lang.String.class;
      const getMethod = SystemProperties.getMethod('get', paramTypes);

      const params = (<any>Array).create(java.lang.Object, 2);

      // Reorder if needed
      const props = ['ro.serialno', 'ril.serialnumber', 'gsm.sn1', 'sys.serialnumber'];

      for(let i = 0, len = props.length; i < len; i++) {

        params[0] = new java.lang.String(props[i]);
        serialNumber = getMethod.invoke(SystemProperties, params);

        if (serialNumber !== '') {
          return serialNumber;
        }
      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    return serialNumber;
  }
}
```

Full code: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=ViNo6g&v=6